# Erro em caractere especial no Java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, codificação-de-caracteres

estou com um problema aqui e não encontrei nada que resolvesse na internet, se puderem me ajudar, ficaria extremamente grato.

Bem, vamos lá, tenho uma aplicação web em java que uso Spring Boot + JSP. O problema é o seguinte: Eu tenho duas aplicações que compartilham o mesmo banco de dados, uma delas grava as coisas e a outra (web) lê, até aí tudo certo, só que quando eu gravo algo da outra aplicação que é Desktop, qualquer coisa que tiver um acento, no banco fica correto mas o Java não consegue ler na parte Web e troca por um caractere estranho.

Eu já tentei:

1. Criar a variável de ambiente: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` com o valor = `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`
2. Adicionar no arquivo `.properties` do Spring a linha `spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;`
3. Mudar a forma da URL do banco: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/banco?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`
4. Tentei configurar no POM.
5. Tentei criar um filter.
6. Tentei alterar o caractere direto pela aplicação, porém, como ela chega do banco até a minha aplicação de forma errada já, isso não adiantou.

Informações importantes:

O banco de dados está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII';

LC_COLLATE = 'C';

LC_CTYPE = 'C'.
```

Se eu gravar algo na parte web, eu consigo ler novamente com o acento normalmente, porém, no banco de dados fica algo assim:

[image: Lixo]

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, garanta que suas JSPs incluam um `<meta charset="UTF-8">` dentro de `<head>` do HTML produzido e antes de qualquer outro conteúdo do `<head>`.

Além disso, na conexão com o PostgreSQL, você usa `characterEncoding=UTF-8`, mas o banco de dados foi configurado com `ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII';`. Você deveria usar `ENCODING = 'UTF8';`. Tal como cita [a documentação do PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html):

> In most cases, if you are working with any non-ASCII data, it is unwise to use the SQL_ASCII setting because PostgreSQL will be unable to help you by converting or validating non-ASCII characters.

Traduzindo:

> Na maioria dos casos, se você está trabalhando com qualquer dado não-ASCII, não é boa ideia utilizar a configuração SQL_ASCII porque o PostgreSQL não será capaz de ajudá-lo ao converter ou validar caracteres não-ASCII.

Além disso, no PostgreSQL, o encoding é definido preferencialmente na hora em que o `CREATE DATABASE` está sendo executado.

Comment: Sim, meus JSP's estão com a meta tag certa, consigo exibir acentuação normalmente neles. O problema mesmo está na chegada do banco de dados até a minha aplicação. No caso, no BD está correto mas, chega na aplicação errado.
Com relação ao characterEncoding=UTF-8, eu coloquei pra ver se resolvia o problema, mesmo sem ele, o problema persiste.
Então não tem uma forma de reverter isso sem trocar diretamente no banco?
Porquê que a aplicação em Delphi (Desktop) consegue manipular o banco normalmente usando caractere especial?

Comment: @GiovaniOliveira O ideal seria você postar na sua pergunta um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável (MVCE). Ou seja, um código completo em Java e configurações do PostgreSQL que outras pessoas possam copiar e testar para reproduzir o seu problema e então buscar soluções. Entretanto, este código seria mínimo, ou seja, teria somente aquilo que serviria para demonstrar o problema e nada mais do que isso.

Comment: Quando você extrai um código MVCE a partir do código do seu programa, você acaba isolando o problema, o que simplifica a busca pela solução e permite a outras pessoas a reproduzi-lo, e na maioria das vezes, você mesmo acaba achando a causa e a solução ao tentar criar o MVCE.

Comment: O problema é que eu não estou fazendo nada demais, apenas dando um "statusDetalhe.getCodErro()", que no banco está com acento mas, na minha aplicação a mensagem chega toda bugada no lugar dos acentos. Já tentei exibir no console mesmo, sem mandar para o JSP, com o mínimo de intervenção possível do Spring e mesmo assim o problema ocorre...